# Convert line endings on save

Tags: vim

As I understand, I can convert line endings from unix to dos this way:

```
:set ff=dos
```

But how I can do it automatically, on save?

For example, I tried:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s\:set\ ff=dos
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `:%s\:` in your `au` doesn't make sense..

If you want to set some option before write, you can just:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * set name=value
```